# What could be causing a small uptick in FCS curve at approximately 10 microseconds

Tags: physical-chemistry

I work as an RA in an academic lab. I've been working with FCS fitting for an experiment, and took FCS curves for fluorescein and calmodulin, displayed with residuals below:

[image: fluorescein FCS curve[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rxlN.png)

I fitted both to an autocorrelation function

$$G(\tau)=1+\frac{T}{(1-T)} \frac{\exp(-\tau/\tau_{trip})}{V_{eff}(c)(1+\tau/\tau_D)\sqrt{1+p^2(\tau/\tau_D)}} $$

As you can see, the fit isn't too bad for preliminary results, but there's a weird uptick at about 1E-5 seconds that isn't accounted for by the model. That it looks about the same for both molecules suggests to me that it may be a small instrumental artifact. I collected both curves at about 6 uW power, 1 nM sample, and averaged five curves for each sample after subtracting an afterpulsing correction found by taking an FCS curve of nanopure water on a slide. I am using a confocal microscope setup. Does anyone know what could be causing an uptick in that timeframe?

Comment: I see undulations in both directions, particularly evident in the residuals. I find it hard to see what you are worried about. Maybe you can draw a circle around the detail that you think stands out. I don't know how the variation in uncertainty in the data points is described in the fits but if the trend of dropping rms noise as you go to longer times is not properly described then the fit routine might try hard to fit the noisy early part (overfitting it) at the expense of the less noisy latter part (which ends up being "misfit").

Comment: It probably won't make much of a difference to the answer, but you might want to report what parameters in the equation are fixed and which are fit (floating).